# Cannot add column in SQL Server ( Incorrect syntax near 'string'.)

Tags: sql-server, alter

I want to add a column to my table in SQL Server. I believe the syntax is correct but I'm still getting this error:

[image: example image]

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? It would have answered this for you straight away.  No need for an SO question.

Comment: Providing text instead of images helps to get faster recommendations from the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is totally wrong - you **cannot** have an `ALTER TABLE` which is followed by both a `DROP COLUMN ....` and an `ADD` afterwards - you need to repeat the `ALTER TABLE` part:

```
ALTER TABLE sample_searches
DROP COLUMN ...... ;

ALTER TABLE sample_searches
ADD search_date DATE NULL, Time INT NULL;
```

Also, since you have `SELECT * FROM taas..sample_searches`, you might need to first switch to the `taas` database before you can run these statements....